# Delayed chained payments also to primary receiver

Tags: php, paypal, chained-payments

I need to do setup a chained payment (using php) that send the money to primary receiver and to a secondary receiver at the same time. In need this to be done after x days the user has given the permission to my website to take that money; 
I need this because the payment depends on a secondary receiver action (if confirm a reservation or not, so if he confirms the reservation, primary and secondary receiver will receive the money, otherwise both receivers won't receive anything).
I found the possibility to setup the delayed payment only for secondary receiver by setting the action type like this:

```
actionType=PAY_PRIMARY     #The PAY_PRIMARY action type delays payment to non-primary receivers
```

I read all the documentation here but I didn't find anything that is right for me:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/